# Definition of "hundreds of ice accretion"

Tags: meteorology, terminology

I saw this line today in a NWS weather alert:

- ACCUMULATIONS...A FEW HUNDREDS OF ICE ACCRETION.

Is this standard terminology?
Does "hundreds (of)" somehow refer to a unit of measure, or
is there a (likely or standard) unit of measure implied or missing here?

http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=MA1255EAFEBC38.WinterWeatherAdvisory.1255EB001010MA.BOXWSWBOX.18aa678bad1893fa8f6667c193e56ef4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's referring to hundredths of an inch, and "hundreds" is a typo for "hundredths". [This FAA information sheet](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/info/all_infos/media/2008/info08024.pdf) says:

> All ice accretion amounts will be reported to the nearest one-hundredth of an inch (0.01 in.). An example of a 1, 3, 6-hour ice accretion remark would be: “I1010 I3015 I6022.” This translates to 0.10 inches of ice in the last hour, 0.15 inches of ice in the last 3 hours, and 0.22 inches of ice in the last 6 hours.

This also matches the terminology used in some other weather reports, such as [this one](https://climate.ncsu.edu/climate/winter_wx/database_details.php?e=605):

> Ice accretion was light, generally only a few hundredths of an inch...